# Hide window created by process

Tags: c#, while-loop, user32

I want to hide a window that is created when I call `p.Start()`. The code I have now does work but my program freezes for about 20-40 seconds because of the while loop that is in there.

Current code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;

//Process p is already created and initialized
p.Start();
while(p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
  p.Refresh();
}

ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
```

Removing the while loop prevents the freezing of my program, but the window doesn't hide then. I did do `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true`, but this only works for console windows.

So, my question is: How can I hide a window created by a process without it freezes my program for 20 seconds

Comment: Have you tried running it with a Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /*YOUR WHILE LOOP*/ })? Maybe the p.Refresh causes a big queued operation that makes your program hang for 20-40 seconds afterwards because of stuff-to-do. Try a Thread.sleep(100); or timer to wait before calling p.Refresh again.

Comment: Creating a new task and running it doesn't work

Comment: Create a processstartinfo with WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, CreateNoWindow = true worked for me on notepad. Tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put this code:

```
while(p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
  p.Refresh();
}

ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
```

in task and run it? It should remove the program freezing.

Comment: It doesn't freeze the program, but now the window opens